# DataTables with Ajax source and aaData initialisation parameter - width of columns different after initial call

Tags: jquery, datatables

As the title says, I'm using an Ajax call to get new data for my tables and using the aaData initialization parameter. The calls all work correctly and repopulate the tables with the correct data. The problem that I have is that although the first table is drawn correctly, all subsequent calls don't auto-size the column widths to fill the entire width of the table - instead, the columns are only as wide as their data.

I'm calling DataTables like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#applyFilter').click(function(){
        //set up vars for ajax options and aoColumns
        $.get('myAjaxsource', options, function(response){
            $('#grid-container').dataTable({
                'aaData': response.AADATA,
                "aoColumns": aoColumns,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bDestroy": true
            });   
        });
    });
}
```

Note: the aoColumns object does not include explicit widths. I've also tried calling fnAdjustColumnSizing() on the DataTables object, but that causes all the tables, including the first call, to have a small width. Also, I've tried removing the bJQueryUI parameter.

The first table generated has a computed width of 1262px. It looks as though the table has a style="width: 100px" attribute inserted after the second call, with a computed width of 322px.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that although I was setting an inline style of "width: 100%", the second call was destroying that and adding its own attribute of "style='width: 100ox'". Putting the style in a stylesheet and marking it !important fixed things.